# How does the infinite union work in $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

Reading a probability theory book, and it says that if we have a sample space $\Omega$, then some class $F$ of subsets of $\Omega$ makes a $\sigma$-algebra and has the following properties:

1) $\Omega\in F$

2) if $A\in F$, then $\complement A\in F$

3) if $A_1,A_2,...\in F$, then ${\stackrel{\infty}{\cup}}_{i=1}A_i\in F$

I don't understand how the last property works, how exactly do we do that infinite number of unions with finite number of elements?

If we have $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4\in F$, does it mean that $A_1\cup A_3\cup...\cup A_3\in F$ ("..." in that case is $A_3$ unioned with itself an infinite number of times)?

Comment: In ${\stackrel{\infty}{\cup}}_{i=1}$ how do I write $i=1$ under $\cup$?

Comment: You can use `\displaystyle` to force the entire scope in which it occurs to be set in display style, which puts limits above and below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and second properties imply that the empty set is always contained in a $\sigma$-algebra: $\varnothing=\Omega^{\mathsf c}\in F$. Consequently, any union of finitely many sets from $F$ can be represented as an infinite union by taking infinitely many copies of the empty set: if, say, $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4\in F$, then $$A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4=A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup A_4\cup\varnothing\cup\varnothing\cup\varnothing\cup\cdots\in F.$$

Comment: what about my second question? do I have to union consecutive elements or can i skip some? Like I asked if $F$ contains $A_1\cup A_3$ when $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4\in F$

Comment: @paulpaul1076 Yes, you can always “skip” elements. Property 3 says that if you take countably many elements from $F$ (which countable family need not be the whole of $F$ and there can be repetitions), then their union is always in $F$. You can represent $A_1\cup A_3 $ as $A_1\cup A_3\cup A_3\cup A_3\cup\cdots$ as you wrote, or as $A_1\cup A_3\cup\varnothing\cup \varnothing\cup\cdots$.

Comment: Oh, so if you have uncountable $F$, then the union of any countable subsets also belongs to $F$, right?

Comment: @paulpaul1076 Exactly.

Comment: I meant union of elements of $F$ that you ordered somehow. I guess saying "countable subsets" is a bit wrong.

Comment: @paulpaul1076 Yeah, I agree: the terminology can be confusing if we’re talking about sets of sets. Just to make sure we’re on the same page, let me clarify: If $F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra over a non-empty set $\Omega$, then the typical element of $F$ is some subset of $\Omega$. Now, that a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under countable unions means the following: if $A_1,A_2,A_3,\ldots$ is a countable collection of elements of $F$ (there can be repetitions), then the union $A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup\cdots$ must be an element of $F$. Nothing here is assumed about the cardinality of $F$.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's just that usually when I see something like $\Sigma_{i=1}$ it means that we add element i, then i+1, then i+2, etc... I guess here you have $F=\{A_1,A_2,A_3,...\}$ and you form a subset of $F$ $F'=\{B_1=A_1\in F, B_2=A_{32}\in F, B_3=A_{55}\in F\}$ and then $\cup_{i=1}B_i \in F$

Comment: @paulpaul1076 Even when $F$ is uncountable (so you cannot enumerate its elements), if you take any countable subcollection $F'\subseteq F$ and take the union of the sets in $F'$, then that union will be in $F$, indeed.

Comment: someone just told me about "Vitali set", which I didn't know about, and it made all of this obvious all of a sudden!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is nothing saying that the countably many $A_i$ need to be distinct. So while we could posit a separate axiom for finite unions, there's no need to do so.